# Logger for loop back 4

Tags: typescript, loopback

How to implement logger in loop back 4 server level.  For every request need to capture status code and request ip.

I have tried using log4j  to create logger but I can only able to call inside my class level. 
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_inject.html

```
    *application.ts:*

    const log4js = require('log4js');

    log4js.configure({
    appenders: { cheese: { type: 'file',     filename: 'cheese.log' } },
    categories: { default: { appenders:    ['cheese'], level: 'error' } }
    });
    const logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');

    //inside application
    app.bind('logger.widget').to(logInfo)
    function logInfo(info: string) {
    logger.info(info);
    }


     *controller.ts class*:

    import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
    export class WidgetController {

    // injection for property
    @inject('logger.widget')
    private logger: Function;

    @get('/hello')
    greet() {
    this.logger("hello request called") 
    return "Hello world";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Please try something and add the code so that the community can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also there is Concept Called Sequence Where request is received before passing to the rest API

Also We can add logger inside Sequence.ts file

Ref: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html

Answer (score 3):

I have found that through Interceptor we can create log.

```
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
import { RestBindings } from '@loopback/rest';
import { Interceptor } from '@loopback/context';

log4js.configure({
  appenders: { cheese: { type: 'dateFile', filename: 'cheese.log', pattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm', compress: true } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['cheese'], level: 'debug' } }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger(process.env.NODE_ENV);

logger.info("Application starts and running")
export const log: Interceptor = async (invocationCtx, next) => {
  // Wait until the interceptor/method chain returns
  const req = await invocationCtx.get(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST);
  logger.info("Requestid - " + uniqid() + "| Request IP -" + req.ip);

  try {
    logger.info('Starting - Class-' + invocationCtx.targetClass.name + ' | Method-' + invocationCtx.methodName);
    //logger.debug("Requestid - " + uniqid() + "| Request IP -" + req.ip);
    const result = await next();
    const res = await invocationCtx.get(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE);

    logger.info('Ending - Class-' + invocationCtx.targetClass.name + ' | Method-' + invocationCtx.methodName);
    logger.info("Response Status Code - " + res.statusCode);

    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
};
```

In your class add interceptor object with that log object

Class:

```
import { intercept } from '@loopback/context';
import {Log} from './Log'
  @intercept(log) // `log` is an interceptor function and above object
export class PingController {
//Your code
 }
```